# Laravel 10 Jetstream | Livewire path error 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I just installed Laravel 10 under WAMP and it works fine.

Then I installed Jetstream but login/ registration pages fail because Livewire path is wrong. How do I fix it ? Can't find it in .env
The tables in laravel dbase are OK, but Livewire.js path is wrong.
Many thanks !

.env

```
APP_URL= http://localhost/laravel/myProject   // laravel files are here
```

livewire.php   // can't find anything to define the path. I believe it's defined in .env

Jetstream Install | As in their website

```
> cd myProject   
> composer require laravel/jetstream
> php artisan jetstream:install livewire

> npm install
> npm run build
> php artisan migrate   // see output below
```

```
   INFO  Preparing database.

  Creating migration table ................................................................................. 10ms DONE

   INFO  Running migrations.

  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ..................................................................... 15ms DONE
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table ..................................................... 12ms DONE
  2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table ................................................... 8ms DONE
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table ............................................................... 13ms DONE
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table .................................................... 20ms DONE
  2023_10_30_130753_create_sessions_table .................................................................. 29ms DONE
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi i solved this problem with this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888115/livewire-js-error-not-found-404-laravel-10-solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888115/livewire-js-error-not-found-404-laravel-10-solved)

Answer (score 0):

Just set your app url like this :
"APP_URL=http://localhost". And run the project with php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

I changed WAMP Apache VirtualHost and /public is now served as /localhost. Everything seems to work fine -out of the box. Thanks